# Sprite Kit Node not detecting collision and not bouncing

Tags: macos, collision-detection, sprite-kit, bounce

Following [RayWenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51108/build-spaceinvaders-in-spritekit-part-2-of-2) i'm having some problem to be able to create a block that makes the bullet bounce in it. But the most disgunting thing is not to be able to detect the collision between the bullet and the brick. Now the bullet pass the brick like it doesn't exist.

Here is the definition of bullet and brick:
Bullet:

```
    bullet = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:kBulletSize];
    bullet.name = kShipFiredBulletName;
    bullet.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:bullet.frame.size];
    bullet.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    bullet.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
    bullet.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    bullet.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kShipFiredBulletCategory;
    bullet.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kInvaderCategory;
    bullet.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0x0;
```

Brick:

```
SKNode* rebote;

rebote = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor orangeColor] size:kBouncetSize];
rebote.position = CGPointMake(550, 500);
rebote.name = @"kBounceBlock";
rebote.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rebote.frame.size];
rebote.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
rebote.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
rebote.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
rebote.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
rebote.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kShipFiredBulletCategory;
rebote.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kInvaderCategory;
rebote.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0x0;

[self addChild:rebote];
```

And here the collision detection method :

```
-(void)handleContact:(SKPhysicsContact*)contact
{
    // Ensure you haven't already handled this contact and removed its nodes
    if (!contact.bodyA.node.parent || !contact.bodyB.node.parent)
        return;

    NSArray* nodeNames = @[contact.bodyA.node.name, contact.bodyB.node.name];
    if ([nodeNames containsObject:kShipName] && [nodeNames containsObject:kInvaderFiredBulletName])
    {
        // Invader bullet hit a ship
        [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"ShipHit.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];
        //1
        [self adjustShipHealthBy:-0.334f];

        if (self.shipHealth <= 0.0f)
        {
            //2
            [contact.bodyA.node removeFromParent];
            [contact.bodyB.node removeFromParent];
        }
        else
        {
            //3
            SKNode* ship = [self childNodeWithName:kShipName];
            ship.alpha = self.shipHealth;

            if (contact.bodyA.node == ship)
                [contact.bodyB.node removeFromParent];
            else
                [contact.bodyA.node removeFromParent];
        }
    }
    else if ([nodeNames containsObject:kInvaderName] && [nodeNames containsObject:kShipFiredBulletName])
    {
         NSLog(@"Contacto entre bala e Invader.");

        // Ship bullet hit an invader
        [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"InvaderHit.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];
        [contact.bodyA.node removeFromParent];
        [contact.bodyB.node removeFromParent];
        //4
        [self adjustScoreBy:100];
    }

    if ([nodeNames containsObject:@"kBounceBlock"])
        NSLog(@"Contacto entre el cuerpo naranja !!");
}
```

Whaat i'm doing wrong ? I defined the restitution property in bullet and in the brick too. The brick is not dynamic and both are in the same 'collisionBitMask'.

I'm pretty lost.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up proper `contactTestBitMask` and `collisionBitMask` for `Brick` and `Bullet`.

For some reasons you have `collisionBitMask` set to `0x0`, which means that node will not collide with any object at all.

Also, you have specified a wrong `categoryBitMask` for `Brick` (the same as for `Bullet`). You should create a separate category for it:

```
bullet.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kShipFiredBulletCategory;
bullet.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kBrickCategory;
bullet.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = kBrickCategory;


rebote.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kBrickCategory;
rebote.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kShipFiredBulletCategory;
rebote.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = kShipFiredBulletCategory;
```

Comment: Thanks your changes works great. Now I can detect the collision between the bullet and the brick. Now we have to work to allow the bullet to bounce when it touches the brick. Now I can detect the collision but the bullet trespass the brick.

Comment: How to you move the bullet? Use `applyForce` to move it

Comment: Note that this is *incorrect* if you want to *detect* the collision between two bodies, as per the original question. `collisionBitMask` is the mask consulted to see if two physical bodies will interact, not whether or not `-handleContact:` will be called. For that, use *contactBitMask* instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `categoryBitMask` is where you assign the category (or categories) a node "belongs" to. The `contactTestBitMask` is where you let a node know which other nodes it should fire a `-handleContact:` for when it collides with them.

You're giving both the nodes above a `contactTestBitMask` of `kInvaderCategory`. That means if either of these nodes collides with a node that has a `categoryBitMask` of `kInvaderCategory`, their `-handleContact:` method will be called. But none of your nodes have a `categoryBitMask` of `kInvaderCategory`, so that will never happen.

If you were, for example, to give your `rebote` node a `contactTestBitMask` of `kShipFiredBulletCategory`, then it would call `-handleContact:` whenever the `bullet` node collided with it because the `bullet` node has a `categoryBitMask` of `kShipFiredBulletCategory`.